# how typecasting & dereferencing works here?

Tags: c++11, pointers, null, type-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b, c;
    char *p = 0;
    int *q = 0;
    double *r = 0;
    cout<<(int)(p + 1);    // printing 1 char size
    cout<<(int)(q + 1);    // printing 4
    cout<<(int)(r + 1);    // printing 8

    int y = 9;
    int *u = &y;
    cout<<(int)(u+1);       //printing 7208688

   cout<<*(p+1);            //not able to dereferance

   }
```

How is type-casting working in both the above case?

Why pointers p, q, r are unable to dereference?

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing any of `p`, `q`, `r`, `p + 1`, `q + 1`, `r + 1` or `u + 1` has undefined behaviour, because none of those pointers point to objects of the correct type.

You can *add* to a pointer, to get a different pointer value. This is only defined for results that stay within the same array, plus the "one-past-the-end" pointer value (treating a pointer to a single object as an array of length one). You can also convert a pointer to an integer type, to get an implementation defined value. Doing those things does not involve dereferencing the pointer.

Adding to a null pointer is also undefined behaviour, because the null pointer does not point to an object, there is nothing to be "one-past-the-end" of.